# using Dagger or Hilt for Android Library Development

Tags: android, gradle, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger-hilt

I am developing an Android Library and investigating if I can use Dagger or Hilt for dependency injection.

If someone is integrating my Android Library( with dagger or hilt dependency latest version) into application that use lower version of Hilt or Dagger Gradle will pick the higher version of Dagger or Hilt. If higher version of library has deprecated/removed some functionality then My Android Library will force application developer to update code as per latest version of Dagger or Hilt.

is it good practice to use Hilt or Dagger for Android Library Development?

Answer (score 1):

Dagger is compile time library. However, for Android library development if Dagger is a dependency, the application needs to include Dagger as a dependency.

https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2685

Comment: This is one of the helpful answers. Thanks, it helped @Inderpal

Answer (score 0):

Dagger will be a much better choice for Android Library Development.
You can manage your dependency graph independently from the client application.
Also, it is not required for the client application to use any DI framework when you use Dagger internally.

Please also check related answer:
[Hilt using in android library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63246625/hilt-using-in-android-library)